# Magento 1.9 Transactional Email Variable Edit

Tags: html, magento, html-email, magento-1.9, transactional-email

So ive tried for 2 months to find the source of my headache to no avail.

Within magentos default transactional emails is for example the "Wishlist" Email, triggered on user input to fill with the specified list of products in the users wishlist and email said list in a grid layout to a recipient of choice.

My problem is this, the HTML for the email specifies only Var_items and Var_grid as the variables that get and input the products into the table. The styling for this table seems to have a fixed pixel size and when inserted into dynamically sized emails it messes them up considerably, my simple goal is to change the styling of these grids to better reflect the emails, but i cannot find it anywhere.

Does anyone have any idea where i should look and what im looking for? Thank you kindly in advance for your assistance. I dont know where else to turn at this point.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template for wishlist items is located at

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/items.phtml
```

take a look at block class Mage_Wishlist_Block_Share_Email_Items

Default template has some fixed values indeed. But you can replace it in your custom theme.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
    <tr>
```

Comment: Dear Vladimir, you are 100% spot on with this, thats amazing, how did you know?

May i ask for your assistance in either learning how you figured it out, or where 2 other functions may be. 

1) Where the styling for the grids themselves are, 
 2)where the styling for the message box, var_message.